# Restrict NSTextField input to numeric only? NSNumberformatter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I'm just getting started up with Mac App Development and so far everything is good well, I'm just having problems trying to get a NSTextField to only accept numbers for the input.

So far I have added a formatter to the NSTextField and set it to only allow decimal now when I enter letters in the field it still allows me but does not allow my to click out of the cell when done.

Ideally I would like the app not to let the user type in any letters and just beep or do nothing.

Any tips or pointers on this would be great

Comment: You can subclass the NSTextField and monitor its input, as shown here: http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2010/11/subclassing-nstextfield-to-allow-only-numbers/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass `NSNumberFormatter` and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString **)partialStringPtr
       proposedSelectedRange:(NSRangePointer)proposedSelRangePtr
              originalString:(NSString *)origString
       originalSelectedRange:(NSRange)origSelRange
            errorDescription:(NSString **)error
```

Comment: Hi Could you explain more on how I could use this code? I'm ideally looking to restrict the input to numeric only with the exception comma and decimal i.e. users can input 12.00 or 12,450

Comment: Well have you read the docs on it? Tell me what from them you don't understand

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike, I have now implemented a custom NSFormatter and can limit the text to just 10 chars using: if ([*partialStringPtr length] > maxLength) { however I am still struggling on how I can restrict the input to numbers and a single decimal point. Sorry for all the questions as you can tell I am very new to all of this.

Comment: After a good nights sleep I managed to solve the problem, I am now using the subclass you mentioned and it is able to check if the input is allowed and also if a decimal place already exists.

Comment: @FlankPlank could you tell us more about your solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to create the same:

Just create the ANYCLASS (called SAMPLE) subclassing the NSNumberFormatter, and in the .m file write the following code...

```
-(BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString *)partialString newEditingString:(NSString **)newString errorDescription:(NSString **) error {
    // Make sure we clear newString and error to ensure old values aren't being used
    if (newString) { *newString = nil;}
    if (error)     {*error = nil;}

    static NSCharacterSet *nonDecimalCharacters = nil;
    if (nonDecimalCharacters == nil) {
        nonDecimalCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet] ;
    }

    if ([partialString length] == 0) {
        return YES; // The empty string is okay (the user might just be deleting everything and starting over)
    } else if ([partialString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonDecimalCharacters].location != NSNotFound) {
        return NO; // Non-decimal characters aren't cool!
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Now in your Actual Class set the formatter to your NSTextField object like this:

```
NSTextField *mySampleTxtFld;
```

And for this set the Formatter:

```
SAMPLE* formatter=[[SAMPLE alloc]init]; // create SAMPLE FORMATTER OBJECT 

self.mySampleTxtFld.delegate=self;
[self.mySampleTxtFld setFormatter:formatter];
```

You’re done!

Comment: This looks like a great solution.

Comment: Great example - really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Rather than subclassing anything, you can do it with an `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` method in your view controller. Set the `delegate` field of the `NSTextField` you want to check and then do something like the following in a `controlTextDidChange:` function which gets called on each character typed. Don't forget to initialize `self.lastValidTimestampCount` in this case. This function uses `RegExLite` to check the value, which may include commas.

```
// Make sure the user has typed a valid number so far.
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    if (obj.object == self.timestampsCount)
    {
        NSString *countValue = timestampsCount.stringValue;
        if (! [countValue isMatchedByRegex:@"^[\\d\\,]{1,6}$"])
        {
            timestampsCount.stringValue = self.lastValidTimestampCount;
            NSBeep();
        }
        else
            self.lastValidTimestampCount = timestampsCount.stringValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
+ (BOOL)stringIsNumber:(NSString *)str {
   BOOL valid;
   double holder;
   NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString: str];
   valid = [scan scanDouble:&holder] && [scan isAtEnd];
  return valid;
}

+ (NSString *)numericStringFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *digitsString = string;
    if (![YOURCLASSNAME stringIsNumber:string]) {
        NSUInteger length = [string length];
        if (length > 0) {
            digitsString = [string substringToIndex:length - 1];
            if (![YOURCLASSNAME stringIsNumber:digitsString]) {
                digitsString = [YOURCLASSNAME numericStringFromString:digitsString];
            }
        }
    }
    return digitsString;
}
```

Then in my controller class, I implement controlTextDidChange:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
   NSString *digitsString = [YOURCLASSNAME numericStringFromString:self.currentCellView.textField.stringValue];
   if (digitsString) {
    self.currentCellView.textField.stringValue = digitsString;
   } else {
    self.currentCellView.textField.stringValue = @"";
   }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that if you paste text into your number field, this will strip out all the non numeric characters from the end of the string until you're left with just a number. Plus it supports an arbitrarily long series of digits. Some of the other approaches would not support putting in a series of digits that couldn't be held in an NSInteger.

I know this approach could certainly be improved though.

Comment: Done.... in the place of Utilities we need to write our class name.. worked for me... thanks.

Comment: Sorry, yes Utilities is just the class that holds the numericStringFromString method which was provided in the answer.

Comment: Hey, this code is working to restrict the numbers but what about if i want to enter only 6 numeric numbers.. trying with your code... no solution.... any help???

Answer (score 1):

NPAssoc's Answer did help me and I did a little change to the code which did not use isMatchedByRegex function.

```
// Make sure the user has typed a valid number so far.
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    if (obj.object == self->number)
    {
        NSString *countValue = number.stringValue;        
        if ([countValue length] > 0) {
            if ([[countValue substringFromIndex:[countValue length]-1] integerValue] > 0 ||
                [[countValue substringFromIndex:[countValue length]-1] isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                self.lastNumber = number.stringValue;
            }
            else
            {
                number.stringValue = self.lastNumber;
                NSBeep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS:Use the [self setIntValue:[self intValue]] limited the length of the input.