# MacRuby: Restrict NSTextField to Integers

Tags: cocoa, integer, macruby

I'm just picking up the basics of Cocoa and Interface Builder -- using IB version 3.2.6. I'm looking to learn how to use MacRuby for native OS X apps.

I have an NSTextField that I would like to only accept integer values. I used NSNumberFormatter but it doesn't seem to have an option to only accept integers.

How would you do this? Can it be done in Interface Builder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict NSTextField input to numeric only? NSNumberformatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652689/restrict-nstextfield-input-to-numeric-only-nsnumberformatter)

Comment: @Andrew Added a naive solution although I don't know if you still need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **naive** but effective approach would be to subclass `NSTextField` and (this is the naive part) ovverride `textDidChange` to **force** the digited value to a number:

In other words, create a new ruby file in your Classes folder add this code to It and change the field class inside IB (your xib > filed you want to change > inspector > Class dropdown)

```
class OnlyNumbersTextField < NSTextField
    def textDidChange(notification)

        self.setIntValue(self.intValue)

    end
end
```

Hope this helps.