# Customize error message in NSTextField with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm working on a little project to learn Objectiv-C. Now I run into a problem:

I had create a Cocoa application with a NSTextField with NumberFormatter. Now, if the user clicks on the text field an try to insert some stuff like "asd" he hears an error peep.

But I want to give the user some future information about the error, maybe with an panel or something like that. How can I receive this error message an can add my own functions?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652689/restrict-nstextfield-input-to-numeric-only-nsnumberformatter

Comment: No not really I don't want to make a subclass of the NSNumberFormatter if a can avoid this.

Is there any other way to connect this function. Maybe with delegates or something like this ...=

Comment: Subclassing appears to be the only way of doing it.

Comment: Ok I will try this and will give you a feedback. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a callback from any method of NSNumberFormatter that returns YES/NO.

Even if it does not have, subclass it and add your own method.

Comment: Why subclass? A category will do

Comment: maybe some properties are required to read strings, store them etc... however in category you can add propeties...thats why i suggested to subclass.